# HD button of video,js player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, video.js

I need HD toggle/ON-OFF button for video.js player like in vimeo player.  Do I have to make a custom button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to understand it's not merely just a button. Button is just a physical UI element that's used to switch between video source.

The concept is that you provided 2 different resolution videos as source to player and the button is used for selecting one of them. e.g if user selects HD, then the source of video changes to the video of better resolution or if it's SD then source changes to low resolution video.

Now coming to what you want to achieve, there's no default HD/SD video switching support in video.js (if my guess is right). You can use a plugin: There's this `video-js-resolutions` plugin by `onyxrev` - available on Github.

Use this plugin: https://github.com/vidcaster/video-js-resolutions

then you can change the css and JS to change the current style to a button that you want.

demo: http://vidcaster.github.io/video-js-resolutions/

I hope it helps.